# Swift Struct boolean values reset after application's quit

Tags: ios, swift, struct

First post here on Stackoverflow.

**Context:** I've been trying to implement Swift code that would load the switch's isOn state (*True*) and save the modified one (if modified) even after closing the view.

**In other words:** Just load switch's default isOn *True* boolean value from Struct. If the switch is switched by the user - change the boolean value (*if statement in the code below*).

**The problem is:** Switch's isOn state is saved and loaded okay after the window is closed and reopened. **However**, the state is again the same as specified in the initializer (in this case *True*) after force quitting the application and reopening it again.
I suspect there is something wrong with the initializer row as it initializes the boolean value as True again and again.

**The question is:** How can I preserve switch's isOn value in Struct after force quitting the app and launching again?

**The code is:**

```
struct sneakers {
    var windy: Bool
}
var sneakersStates = sneakers.init(windy: true)

class CustomizationViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var windySwitch: UISwitch!

    @IBAction func windySwitched(_ sender: UISwitch) {
            if windySwitch.isOn == true {
                sneakersStates.windy = true
            } else {
                sneakersStates.windy = false
            }
    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    windySwitch.isOn = sneakersStates.windy
}
```

Comment: Look at `UserDefaults` if you need to preserve values across launches: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults

Comment: This might help [A type-safe UserSefaults in Swift](https://medium.com/swlh/a-type-safe-userdefaults-in-swift-45a5cfc54b1b?source=friends_link&sk=5dcc3a5cc3b4098dcda3ed9b34c5c84f)

Comment: Thank you! Applied UserDefaults to set and retrieve booleans. That worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing the code like this with **UserDefaults** class:

```
class CustomizationViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var windySwitch: UISwitch!

@IBAction func windySwitched(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.isOn, forKey: "sneakersWindySwitchedState") //Sets switch's isOn value on change
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let headLaunchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "headLaunchedBefore")
    if headLaunchedBefore  { //executed on non-First Launch
        windySwitch.isOn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "sneakersWindySwitchedState") //Loads switch's isOn value
    } else { //executed on First Launch
        windySwitch.isOn = true
        UserDefaults.standard.set(windySwitch.isOn, forKey: "sneakersWindySwitchedState") //Sets default switch's isOn true value on change
}
```